# highcharts SVG drawing mousemove

Tags: highcharts, line, mousemove

we need to implement similar functionality as below..

http://www.barchart.com/interactive_charts/stocks/PFE

then click on Tools --> Trendline and then click on chart SVG and drag line and when you release mouse it draws line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Annotation plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/17/Annotations) for that.

Comment: does this takes care of zoom with dateTime Axis ?